# I want to grab all my data from my forms and save to the DB

Tags: django, forms, save

I wanna  grab those fields and save to my db. But i get this error.

'User() got unexpected keyword arguments: speciality, start_year.... etc etc'

I have two types of user Student and Teacher. So i have a custom user model.

i have almost 3 months learning Django. I hope you can help me, thank you.

#My forms.

```
class StudentSignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Email",
            }
        )
    )

    username = forms.CharField(
        min_length=3,
        max_length=20,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Username"}
        ),
    )

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "First name"}
        ),
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Last name"}
        ),
    )

    nation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=NATIONALITY_CHOICES, required=False)

    sex = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, required=False)

    phone = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Phone"}),
    )

    address = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Address"}
        ),
    )

    department = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, required=False)
    speciality = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SPECIALITY_CHOICES, required=False)

    shift = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SHIFT_CHOICES, required=False)

    plan = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, required=False)

    medical_notes = forms.Textarea()

    campus = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CAMPUS_CHOICES, required=False)

    password = forms.CharField(
        label="password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": " Insert a password",
                "id": "password",
                "required": "required",
            }
        ),
    )

    password_confirmation = forms.CharField(
        label="password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": " Confirm your password",
                "id": "password_confirmation",
                "required": "required",
            }
        ),
    )

    def clean(self):
        """Verify password confirmation match."""
        data = super().clean()

        password = data["password"]
        password_confirmation = data["password_confirmation"]

        if password != password_confirmation:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")

        return data

    def save(self):
        """Create user and profile."""
        data = self.cleaned_data
        data.pop("password_confirmation")
        User.objects.create_user(**data)
```

Comment: Add whole error message and User class code to your question. Since your error says that User class got unexpected arguments the problem is probably there.

Answer (score 0):

[And heres the image with my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmlYs.png)

My custom user model.

```
# Local
from core.models import BaseModel

# TPP
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



class User(BaseModel, AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name},{self.last_name}'

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


#And my student model


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE
                                )
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SPECIALITY_CHOICES)
    start_year = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    nation = models.CharField(choices=NATIONALITY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField()                            
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    department = models.CharField(choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, max_length=13)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SHIFT_CHOICES)
    period = models.CharField(help_text='2020-02-04', max_length=20, 
    blank=True, null=True)
    plan  = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=14)
    medical_notes = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    campus = models.CharField(choices=CAMPUS_CHOICES, max_length=13)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```